# Balance Trend Analysis

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I was looking to do a running percentage change each month of balances by product. The month field is representative of the last business day of each month.

I have tried using a common table expression as below:

```
declare @tab table 
( DATE DATETIME, 
BALANCE DECIMAL (38,8), 
PDCT_TYPE_C VARCHAR (5), 
EXCL_C VARCHAR (1) 
)

INSERT INTO @tab 
SELECT 
DATE, 
SUM(BALANCE),
PDCT_TYPE_C,
RC_EXCL_C 
from ERIC..RC_XPOS 
WHERE RC_EXCL_C IS NULL AND PDCT_TYPE_C = 'hln' 
GROUP BY XPOS_D,PDCT_TYPE_C,RC_EXCL_C 
; 
with cte as 
( 
select 
row_number() over (order by PDCT_TYPE_C,DATE) rn, 
DATE, 
BALANCE, 
PDCT_TYPE_C 
from @tab 
) 
select 
DATE, 
BALANCE, 
(((select BALANCE from cte where cte.rn=1))-(select BALANCE from cte where cte.rn=t1.rn+1)) as 'EAD MOM Difference', 
(((select BALANCE from cte where cte.rn=1))/(select BALANCE from cte where cte.rn=t1.rn+1)) as 'EAD MOM % Difference', 
PDCT_TYPE_C 
from cte as t1
```

This was works fine if there is one product, the problem though is if there is many products it just calculates the percentage change on the row before- which might be a different product when there are multiple product types.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I'm hoping for results like below. I have the balance,date and Product type fields  available but am hoping to calculate the balance difference and balance change without having to do a row partition and calculation based on the row above.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Desired result:

```
Date        | Balance      | Balance Difference | Balance % Change |  Product Type
---------------------------------------------------------------
30/06/2017  | 4,000,000.00 | --                 | --               | AP
30/06/2017  | 2,000,000.00 | --                 | --               | ZA
30/06/2017  | 1,000,000.00 | --                 | --               | LP
31/07/2017  | 5,000,000.00 |1,000,000.00        | 0.25             | AP            
31/07/2017  | 2,000,000.00 |1,000,000.00        | 0.5              | LP 
31/07/2017  | 1,000,000.00 |-1,000,000.00       | -0.5             | ZA
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    Balance MONEY NOT NULL,
    ProductType CHAR(2) NOT NULL 
    );

INSERT #TestData (Date, Balance, ProductType) VALUES
    ('2017-06-30', 4000000, 'AP'),
    ('2017-06-30', 2000000, 'ZA'),
    ('2017-06-30', 1000000, 'LP'),

    ('2017-07-31', 5000000, 'AP'),
    ('2017-07-31', 1000000, 'ZA'),
    ('2017-07-31', 2000000, 'LP');

SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

--==================================================

SELECT 
    td.Date, 
    td.Balance, 
    [EAD MOM Difference] = td.Balance - LAG(td.Balance, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY td.ProductType ORDER BY td.Date),
    [EAD MOM % Difference] = td.Balance / LAG(td.Balance, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY td.ProductType ORDER BY td.Date) - 1,
    td.ProductType
FROM
    #TestData td
ORDER BY
    td.Date,
    td.ProductType;

--==================================================
--==================================================
-- SQL Server (pre 2012) version...
WITH 
    cte_TestDataRN AS (
        SELECT 
            td.Date, td.Balance, td.ProductType,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY td.ProductType ORDER BY td.Date)
        FROM
            #TestData td
        )
SELECT 
    tdr1.Date,
    tdr1.Balance,
    [EAD MOM Difference] = tdr1.Balance - tdr2.Balance,
    [EAD MOM % Difference] = tdr1.Balance / tdr2.Balance - 1,
    tdr1.ProductType
FROM
    cte_TestDataRN tdr1
    LEFT JOIN cte_TestDataRN tdr2
        ON tdr1.ProductType = tdr2.ProductType
        AND tdr1.RN = tdr2.RN + 1
ORDER BY 
    tdr1.Date,
    tdr2.ProductType;
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that unfortunately I only have access to SQL Server 2008, so I can't use the Lag function or Partition by the product,order by date etc . I will have to use a CTE to do this

Comment: I've updated the solution to include a "pre 2012" version.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I got it working a couple of days back, makes sense to me. I have columns returning percentage change month on month and 3 month percentage change.I am now trying to calculate the difference each month from  the 30 June, how would I do this given the 30 June record would have a different row number based on the product and number of records.